# Release configuration not available in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, configuration, release-mode

I have a web application in 2012, which I suppose converted from 2010 solution. It has only one configuration "Debug" listed in toolbar, configuration manager and publish wizard. Is there any settings to be changed in the web.config or other places? I don't think its a setting at visual studio level because other new projects has both the Debug and Release settings

Answer (score 2):

The configurations that are available, are part of the solution file. When you open the *.sln file with a text editor, you will finde a section that looks like this:

`GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    Release|x86 = Release|x86
EndGlobalSection`

In your case, I assume that the (in this example two) entries for `Release` are missing. In order to add a new configuration to your solution, you have use the *Configuration Manager*.

Menu -> Build -> Configuration Manager... under *Active Solution Configurations* you can add a new config for *Release*.