# I'm not getting Release Debug Option in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I am working on an old project and have changed a lot in it. but its not Updating my Project's dll.

I came through this [Link](http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2012/03/25/asp.net-.refresh-dlls-not-updated-or-copied-in-webdeployment-.wdproj.aspx) which says that I need to build my Project under Release Configuration. But I'm not getting that option.

[image: Configuration Manager]

Is there any thing that I can do?

Comment: You can click *<New...>* and add one.

Comment: I added _<New..>_ as release but didn't get it in Batch Build Option

Comment: Is this still an issue? If yes, could you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30014382/937093) question and it's answer?